# scp error while attempting to copy files

Tags: scp

I use `scp` to transfer files from my android to my MacBook which works like a charm. But I have a folder called `John's folder` on my MacBook so when I attempt to copy a file inside that directory like 
`scp macbook@192.168.0.3:/Users/macbook/desktop/John\'s\ folder/file storage/folder`

It throws back an error

```
unexpected EOF error while looking for matching \`’\`
```

and

```
unexpected end of file
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Try using double quotes instead: `scp "macbook@192.168.0.3:/Users/macbook/desktop/John's folder/file storage/folder"`.  But also just don't give files/directories such crazy names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As of [OpenSSH version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0) released on 2022-04-08, the `scp` program now uses the SFTP protocol directly. As a consequence the original issue no longer exists, and therefore the remainder of this answer is no longer required.*

*If you are using a legacy version of `scp`, or you want to revert to the old SCP protocol with `scp -O`, the answer still applies.*

*Original answer follows.*

---

This is interesting. The other answers that I'm seeing are telling you to swap your escaped quote and escaped space for a quoted string. Actually they're equivalent so you'll see no change (`a\'\ b` is the same to the shell as `"a' b"`).

The problem here lies in the way that `scp` on the *remote system* interprets the command line that it's being given.

As an example, this would work:

```
scp John\'s\ folder/file localhost:/tmp/dst
```

But this would fail:

```
scp localhost:/tmp/src/John\'s\ folder/file /tmp/dst
```

(I've used `localhost` for the example; you should use `user@host` for your situation.)

If you include the `-v` (*verbose*) flag on `scp` you can see exactly what's going on that gives rise to the failure:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f /tmp/src/John's folder/file
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The unfortunate solution here is that you need to escape special characters (including whitespace) twice - once for the local shell, and once for the remote shell:

```
scp localhost:"/tmp/src/John\'s\ folder/file" /tmp/dst
```

Answer (score 0):

SCP needs to include one entire parameter in quotations. 2 different answers before me are partially right, but the correct answer is

`scp "macbook@192.168.0.3:/Users/macbook/desktop/John's folder/file" storage/folder`

Notice that the first parameter is wrapped in quotes, but not the second - if both were wrapped in a single instance of quotations as one comments suggests, the /bin/scp would invoke this as a single parameter, and be expecting another parameter after that.

`scp "macbook@192.168.0.3:/Users/macbook/desktop/John's folder/file storage/folder"` will be read as a single parameter. Even though there is a space there, the double quotes escape that.

Finally, putting quotations in the middle of a parameter like `scp macbook@192.168.0.3:"/Users/macbook/desktop/John's folder/file" storage/folder` cuts the paarameter in half and won't make sense to the shell because user@host:/path/to/directory is one full parameter. You can use parts of it, but you cannot cut it in half or it will be examined as 2 different params.

Comment: Changing quotes within a token (aka word) works fine in any POSIX shell. Example (in bash): `foo=bar; echo fine'$foo'more"$foo"` -> `fine$foomorebar`

Answer (score 0):

Triple escape works for me:

```
scp macbook@192.168.0.3:bob\\\'s\\\ file /local/path/
```

These also work:

```
scp "macbook@192.168.0.3:bob\'s\ file" /local/path/
scp macbook@192.168.0.3:"bob\'s\ file" /local/path/
```

These do not:

```
scp "macbook@192.168.0.3:bob's file" /local/path/
scp macbook@192.168.0.3:bob\'s\ file /local/path/
```