# Copy mail file from maildir over ssh

Tags: debian, scp, maildir

The maildir has a specific format of the files laying underneath, e.g. *1549464014.9224_427.hostname:2,RS*. In Debian environment copying this file over SSH without renaming is impossible or I don't know how. The question is how?

**NOTE:** no renaming should be involved!

The example output:

```
[user@hostname ~]$ scp '1549464014.9224_427.hostname:2,RS' remote.server.com:/dest/dir/
1549464014.9224_427.hostname:22: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

The solution with quotation like in [scp error while attempting to copy files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438791/scp-error-while-attempting-to-copy-files) is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
scp './1549464014.9224_427.hostname:2,RS' remote.server.com:/dest/dir/
```

see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148934/330217

Comment: Lol, you were faster 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory where your files are and type

```
scp './<filename>' user@server:location
```

Replace filename with your filename, it should work. Basically, it was looking for filename elsewhere